# AWN main menu crashed, won't restart

Tags: menu, awn

I restarted my pc, and the icon in the bottom left of the screen is a frowny face. When I hoover on it it says "Whoops! The applet crashed. Click to restart it." I click on it, the circle moves around, then the frowny face is back. I've tried right-clicking on the rest of the bar and going into the config files, but I did not find anything out of place. What do I do from here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your using gnome desktop. The applet crashed and cant recover. I had a similar problem with Zorin 6 (based on Ubuntu 12.04). To fix this I right

- clicked on the menu bar and select dock preference
- Then select applets
- Find your menu applet here (for me it was title "yet another menu applet") and should be near the bottom
- Now you can place a working menu app where the old menu app was (drag and drop)
- and you can remove the dead menu app from the bar.

If this doesn't work just comment on the answer and I can try to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

To start, can you post your /var/log/syslog to see if awn-menu-applet is reporting any errors. Next, have you attempted running sudo awn-menu-applet or its corresponding command to attempt to reinitialize in the terminal? If these produce no fruits then I'm out of any beneficial ideas.